# App Engine AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'events'

Tags: google-app-engine

I had this error 20 times on the same instance, and then it went away after the instance was killed because of processing too many sequential errors. No changes were made in my code, and this is the only time I have seen this happen.

Questions:

- What type of problem in my code might be causing this to happen only with some instances? I have no idea where to start looking since I can't recreate the problem.
- Is there a way to decrease the number of sequential errors allowed by an instance before it is killed so this won't create much disruption if it happens again?

This is the first log I have from this instance (no error):

```
2012-10-05 18:41:03.266 /rpc/?action=ServerAvailable 500 60908ms 0kb popwords/1.2         CFNetwork/548.1.4 Darwin/11.4.2
98.207.195.103 - - [05/Oct/2012:11:41:03 -0700] "GET /rpc/?action=ServerAvailable HTTP/1.1" 500 0 - "popwords/1.2 CFNetwork/548.1.4 Darwin/11.4.2" "www.popwordsapp.appspot.com" ms=60909 cpu_ms=498 loading_request=1 instance=00c61b117c8f8b7f701c0776284c25a64c7ff329
I 2012-10-05 18:41:03.265
This request caused a new process to be started for your application, and thus caused your application code to be loaded for the first time. This request may thus take longer and use more CPU than a typical request for your application.
```

This is the next log from this instance (first one with error):

```
2012-10-05 18:49:38.704 /rpc/?action=ServerAvailable 500 867ms 0kb popwords/1.2 CFNetwork/548.1.4 Darwin/11.4.2
98.207.195.103 - - [05/Oct/2012:11:49:38 -0700] "GET /rpc/?action=ServerAvailable HTTP/1.1" 500 0 - "popwords/1.2 CFNetwork/548.1.4 Darwin/11.4.2" "www.popwordsapp.appspot.com" ms=867 cpu_ms=86 instance=00c61b117c8f8b7f701c0776284c25a64c7ff329
E 2012-10-05 18:49:38.103
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 195, in Handle
handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 239, in _LoadHandler
handler = __import__(path[0])
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~popwordsapp/1.362183705604897547/main.py", line 40, in <module>
from google.appengine.ext import db
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/db/__init__.py", line 98, in <module>
from google.appengine.api import datastore
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/datastore.py", line 62, in <module>
from google.appengine.datastore import datastore_query
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/datastore/datastore_query.py", line 64, in <module>
from google.appengine.datastore import datastore_index
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/datastore/datastore_index.py", line 62, in <module>
from google.appengine.api import yaml_object
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/yaml_object.py", line 36, in <module>
from google.appengine.api import yaml_listener
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/yaml_listener.py", line 34, in <module>
    yaml.events.StreamStartEvent: 'StreamStart',
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'events'
```

In between these two logs there was one log where an additional instance was created (no error). None of the errors come from this other instance that was created immediately after the first one. It started handling requests successfully after the first instance was killed because of processing too many sequential errors.

Comment: Can you check your logs and see if the first request to that instance had a DeadlineExceededError? If so, this is a known issue that the instance is in a half-initialised state and the only way to recover is to shutdown the instance.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look. No, it did not. I have edited my question to add the first two logs and a bit more detail.

Comment: There was definitely an error on the first request (the 500, and it took longer than 60 seconds). The next request is also interesting in that for some reason, it's doing application loading which should only be done for the first request to a given handler.

Answer (score 0):

I see this error occasionally after I deploy code, and a redeploy usually stops it. Not that helpful, I know, but hopefully this is something that google will fix on their end soon.

Comment: This would be better contributed as a comment. It may be useful but it is not an answer.

Comment: I am guessing this is just because a new instance is spawned when you redeploy that removes the bad one, so I don't think this is a permanent fix for keeping bad instances from appearing to begin with.